# ORM query many to many to one, Flask sql-alchemy

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three flask-sqlalchemy-models. `Books` - unique entries by admin:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    book_name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.book_name
```

`Bookscomp` - entries by users, related to above:

```
class Bookscomp(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    book = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
```

`Company` - user, related to above:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    books = db.relationship('Bookscomp', secondary=companybook, lazy='dynamic',
        backref=db.backref('company'))

companybook = db.Table('companybook',
    db.Column('companyid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('bookid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bookscomp.id'), primary_key=True),
                                )
```

**Problem**: I am trying to get `book_name` from `Book` model, through `Company` + `Bookscomp`.
So a company has many books and each book has reference to general book info. 
**Tried** like this:

```
company = OrganizatCompanyion.query.filter_by(id=comp.id).first()
    books = company.books.all()
for item in books:
        print(item.book.book_name)
        #AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 
        print(item.book)
        #Gives book id from book model, but I need name
```

Why I cannot get `book_name` in the above code snippet directly? And how would it be best to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined a relationship between `Book` and `Bookcomp` so when you ask for `item.book`-- it's getting the `book = db.Column(db.Integer...` value.  Maybe tweak your `Bookscomp` model to be something like:

```
class Bookscomp(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'))
    book = db.relationship('Book')
```